# "Я знаю (то), что ты обманула меня."

Tags: грамматика, выбор-слов, грамотная-речь, правила, частица

Насколько я понимаю, классические правила русского языка запрещают опускать частицу ***то*** в предложениях вроде

> Я знаю ***то***, что ты обманула меня.

Правда ли, что опускать здесь ***то*** стало современной литературной нормой? Я всегда так делал, и начал сомневаться только после знакомства с правилами.

Comment: Вы очень своевременно этот вопрос затронули. Сейчас действительно стало "модным" добавлять это "то", к сожалению. И это особенно популярно в детской среде вроде. По крайней мере я от детей это гораздо чаще слышал, чем от кого-то ещё, последнее время. Мне очень нравится затронутая тема, но, признаться, я всё же не поставил плюсик только из-за того, что меня сильно расстроило, что Вы считали это новое веяние старой нормой, которая сейчас якобы утрачивается, то есть с точностью до наоборот.

Comment: Вопрос дублируется на другом SE сайте, зачем?

Comment: @V.V., да, спасибо. А как понять, задавать ли вопрос здесь или в англоязычной версии?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Насколько я понимаю, классические правила русского языка запрещают
>   опускать частицу ***то*** в предложениях вроде
>
> *Я знаю **то**, что ты обманула меня.*

Гм... По-моему, Вы что-то путаете. **Таких** правил нет сейчас, не было и два века назад.

**[Пушкин](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=%28metas%253A%2522author%2522%2520%2526%2520%28%21%25EF%25F3%25F8%25EA%25E8%25ED%29%29&mysent=&mysize=397010&mysentsize=33966&mydocsize=496&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E7%ED%E0%FE%20%F7%F2%EE%20%F2%FB)** в подобных предложениях обходился без ***то:***

> ***Знаю, что*** ты служил...
>
> ***знаю что*** ты во все тяжкое не пустишься...
>
> ***знаю что*** ты живъ...
>
> ***знаю, что*** ты со мною спорить не станешь...

Comment: Слава, а почему перед "что" нету запятых в половине примеров? Может, всё-таки поставить их?

Comment: _Артём Луговой: а почему перед "что" нету запятых в половине примеров?_ === Потому что письма Пушкина никто не корректировал. И нам с Вами не стоит этого делать.

Comment: Вот тоже интересный вопрос, почему считается правильным оставлять какие-то ошибки, как у автора. Другое дело, когда это авторский знак, вольность и т. д., пускай это и формально ошибка, но в этом проявляется его стиль, и правильно это не трогать. Но когда очевидно, что это просто по недосмотру ошибка или опечатка, почему нельзя исправить, как Вы считаете?

Comment: Артем, во времена Пушкина не было четко сформулированных правил, и запятая в этом случае не считалось ошибкой. Поэтому в данном случае ставить запятую неуместно, по крайнем мере в данном примере.

Comment: Отсутствие не считалось, наверно? Меня интересует, почему необходимо сохранять пунктуацию оригинала и нельзя привести разные примеры Пушкина к единообразию так, чтобы новый вариант был одним из вариантов того времени. Конечно, я не предлагаю заменять то, что тогда было **всегда** отлично от нынешнего, современным вариантом, а только в том случае, если он был одним из и тогда.

Comment: *Меня интересует, почему необходимо сохранять пунктуацию оригинала и нельзя привести разные примеры Пушкина к единообразию...?* - это хороший вопрос. Тут нет единого мнения, *надо ли* на это прокрустово ложе единообразие все класть, а уж на "почему?" надо или не надо ответов столько, что трудео даже ориентироваться. Одно могу сказать, время от времени одна из точек зрения начинает возобладать - и тогда получаем новую редакцию. Если очень кратно, то сейчас, насколько знаю, выделяют три основных группы "авторского" правописания.

Comment: а) Ошибки/опечатки (с пазделение на авторские и корректорские) б) умышленные авторские отступления от действующих норм, в) особенности, связанные с современным автору своду правил (не слушайте Сержа, он в том или ином виде был с незапамятных времен, пусть не полный, и не всеми во всем признаваемый, но был). Так вот однозначно "приводят к единообразию" только третью группу. С остальными двумя, равно как и внесистемными особенностями обращаются весьма бережно, ибо очень трудно взять на себя ответственность признать классика ошибающимся в неочевидных случаях.

Comment: Артем,  есть книги, где сохранена авторская пунктуация, а есть те, где текст печатается в современной орфографии. И это обычно оговаривается в предусловии книге.

Comment: А  behemothus, как всегда,мнит из себя великого лингвиста.

Answer (score 3):

Сложноподчиненные предложения с изъяснительной придаточной частью могут иметь в главной соотносительные слова. Они могут использоваться для усиления, выделения, подчеркивания объекта речи. В таких случаях относительные слова не являются обязательными.

Такое соотносительное слово может быть опущено.

> Приятно было иногда вспомнить, что здесь, где-то недалеко, ходит приятель и земляк Володя Травкин (Казак.). - Приятно было иногда вспомнить то, что...

Соотносительное слово необходимо в следующих случаях.

> Соотносительное слово входит в состав неразложимого словосочетания (заключаться в том, выражаться в том, состоять в том и др.; глаголы, входящие в такие словосочетания, без управляемых местоимений лексически не сочетаются с изъяснительной частью): Цель эксперимента состоит в том, чтобы уравновесить водой гидростатический столб крови («Смена»).
>    Неразложимое словосочетание, прикрепляющее изъяснительную часть, может иметь в качестве главного слова и имя существительное (например, дело в том): Дело в том, что подполковник Галиев, узнав о приезде Аниканова, после короткого размышления решил оставить Мещерского здесь (Казак.).
>
> Соотносительные слова необходимы и в тех случаях, когда они стоят при глаголах, которые хотя и не составляют с ними неразложимого словосочетания, но лексически не допускают изъяснительной части, прикрепленной к ним непосредственно: Шум походил на то, как бы вся комната наполнилась змеями (Г.).
>    Не допускают изъяснительной части без соотносительных слов и некоторые прилагательные: Он уже был давно известен тем, что в другом городе и в другой труппе, играя в «Принцессе Грезе» зеленого рыцаря, он упал и покатился в своих жестяных латах к рампе, громыхая, как огромный самовар (Купр.).
>
> Соотносительные слова необходимы при противопоставлении и связанном с ним отрицании: Он мечтал не о том, чтобы поскорее закончить институт, а чтобы как можно больше приобрести знаний.
>
> Необходимость местоимения в главной части в качестве соотносительного слова обнаруживается и в том случае, когда оно включается в перечислительный ряд: Все было отлично - и то, что я впервые уезжаю один в лагерь, и то, что уезжаю далеко, куда-то под Смоленск, на неизвестную реку Вопь, и то, что пробуду там все лето, а значит, не поеду с матерью в какую-нибудь деревню, где она опять будет пичкать меня с утра до вечера парным молоком и следить за каждым моим шагом

Современный русский язык. Валгина, Розенталь, 2002.

Answer (score 2):

Правила фиксируют языковую практику и условности правописания; они могут служить ориентиром, но "конструирование" речи по правилам не гарантирует её естественности. Поэтому не так важно, существовало ли когда-нибудь правило, которое вам запомнилось. При порядке слов, выбранном в вашем примере, и при нейтральном контексте носители языка в большинстве своём предпочтут обойтись без "то": "*Я знаю, что ты обманула меня*". Пример контекста, когда "то" оправдано тем, что используется для указания на уже упомянутый собеседником факт (обратите внимание и на другой порядок слов):

> -- Я тебя обманула.
>
> -- То, что ты обманула меня, я знаю. (Меня сейчас интересует другое.)

Answer (score 1):

*"Я знаю, о чем ты просишь". "Я понимаю, к чему ты клонишь".*

Я не профессиональный филолог, но конечно правда! Если 99,9% людей так выражаются, не надо ждать, пока какие-то академики зафиксируют новое правило. Кстати, о каком правиле идет речь? Действительно ли то, о чем вы говорите, было нормой? Вот в предыдущем моем предложении, например, опускать "то" нельзя. :)

Answer (score 1):

slava1947 абсолютно прав. Я добавлю тут, чтобы комментариями не мучить.

> Я знаю то, что ты обманула меня.

А частица ли это? Больше смахивает но местоимение. Частицей это "то" является только в некоторых случаях, когда она "пристыковывается" к основному слову (пишется обычно через дефис) для усиления, да и то по современному понимаю - не всегда.

Во фразах типа "Ну это-то я знаю" "-то" - частица, но её можно опустить.

А вот в словах типа "когда-то", "где-то" и проч. опускать её никак нельзя было по классическим правилам, но по современным выражения типа "ну может, когда и было" (вместо "когда-то и было") стали возможными. Но при этом нет единого понимания, что "-то" здесь частица, а не суффикс.

Так что, как ни крути, а даже предположить, с чем вы спутали, формулируя свое правило про ***частицу***, даже предположить трудно.

Comment: *Во фразах типа "Ну что-то я знаю" "-то" - частица, но её можно опустить.* Опустить? И какой же смысл тогда получится? Я лично не понимаю... "Ну" тут не междометие? Если частица (без запятой), тогда вообще никакого смысла не вырисовывается. То есть смысл получится, если продолжить, но совсем другой.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Проошу прощения, идиотская опечатка, как всегда. не "что-то", а "это-то". Спасибо, исправил.

Comment: Ничего, бывает)